# PHP Multidimensional sort?

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a rather annoying array structure to work with and I need to sort it by any arbitrary key combination. 2 records are displayed below but multiple records with or without the same structure will be present when sorting is actioned.

Here are two records.

```
Array(

    [0] => Array
    (
        [cid] => 1
        [title] => Mr
        [first_name] => Abet
        [last_name] => Simbad
        [emails] => Array
        (
            [374] => Array
            (
                [eid] => 374
                [name] => ski lodge
                [email] => simbad@skifree.com
            )

            [373] => Array
            (
                [eid] => 373
                [name] => work
                [email] => simbad@work.com
            )

            [375] => Array
            (
                [eid] => 375
                [name] => personal
                [email] => simbad@gmail.com
            )
        )
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [cid] => 2
        [title] => Mrs
        [first_name] => Angie
        [last_name] => Stokes
        [emails] => Array
        (
            [590] => Array
            (
                [eid] => 590
                [name] => work
                [email] => angie@gmail.com
            )
        )
    )
```

So if I wanted to sort by `email` in ascending order in the `emails` array, how can I get the second complete record to come first in the result array? angie@gmail.com comes before simbad@....

Also Some records will not contain an emails array. They would be last in the result set.
Any help would be much appreciated.

The array shown is a cut down version but I have addresses, notes, phones and websites in the same annoying structure. Ideally I could sort with something like

```
$sort = array('emails','email')
$data = sort_data_func('ASC',$sort,$data);
```

But anything steps in the right direction will help. :)

Here's some code I have so far

```
$sort = array('emails','email');
foreach($contacts as $ckey => $c){
    if(is_array($c[$sort[0]])){
        foreach($c[$sort[0]] as $key1 => $sort0){
            if($sort0[$sort[1]]!=''){
                $res[$sort[0]][$ckey][$sort[1]][] = $sort0[$sort[1]];
            }
        }
    }
}
print_r($res);
```

Which produces:

```
Array
(
    [emails] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => simbad@skifree.com
            [1] => simbad@work.com
            [2] => simbad@gmail.com
        )
        [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => angie@gmail.com
        )
    )
)
```

But I have no idea where to go from here.

**EDIT** 
OK I have the records in the currect order now but how can I keep the initial record ID in the resulting array?
Here's what I'm using.

```
$direction=='ASC'

function cmp_asc($a, $b){
    $key = current(array_keys($a));
    sort($a[$key]);
    $a[$key] = current($a[$key]);
    sort($b[$key]);
    $b[$key] = current($b[$key]);
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

function cmp_desc($a, $b){
    $key = current(array_keys($a));
    asort($a[$key]);
    $a[$key] = current($a[$key]);
    asort($b[$key]);
    $b[$key] = current($b[$key]);
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

if($direction=='ASC'){
    usort($res[$sort[0]], 'cmp_asc');
}else{
    usort($res[$sort[0]], 'cmp_desc');
}
```

**In**

```
Array
(
    [emails] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [email] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => simbad@skifree.com
                            [1] => simbad@work.com
                            [2] => simbad@gmail.com
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [email] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => angie@gmail.com
                        )

                )
        )
)
```

**Out**

```
Array
(
    [emails] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [email] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => angie@gmnail.com
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [email] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => simbad@skifree.com
                            [1] => simbad@work.com
                            [2] => simbad@gmail.com
                        )

                )

        )
)
```

Comment: Standard question: what is your approach so far? Where are you stuck with your solution? Provide us with some more PHP code of you please.

Comment: OK, I'll try to make it a bit more understandable as it's in the middle of a lot of other code. My problem is accessing the last level of the array without knowing the key. I'm trying to avoid loops because the result set is in the thousands.

Comment: [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) + self-written comparison function == done

Comment: usort would be great if there were only one email per record but there are multiple

Comment: Very close now, I just need to maintain the array index in the output array.

Comment: @CBroe UASORT does the trick thanks. Add an answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) functions, combined with a self-written comparison function that detects the order in which two elements should be sorted, should do the trick.